# eslint is giving a read only error when requiring a react component?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am using react and before defining one of my components I require a different component like this: var Storage = require('./StorageHistory');
eslint is giving me the error: "Storage" is read only no-undef. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storage` is an interface to access localStorage or sessionStorage. It's a global variable in browsers and you are overriding it. Because of that ESLint is notifying you about potential error.

You can find more information about `Storage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).